# change default theme in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

how can change default theme in angular material?

For change from `indigo-pink.css` to `purple-green.css`

In `angular.json` I change from

```
 "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ]
```

to

```
 "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ]
```

But after changing the style, materials element are not displayed...

I import css but still does not show material element.
[image]
please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In angular 8 we must create `src\styles.scss` file with

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css';
```

Then add `styles.scss` to angular.json like this

```
"styles": ["src/styles.scss"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the official blog in [here](https://next.material.angular.io/guide/theming), you can try to include this one line in your global `styles.css` file:

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need also delete .angular folder in your app and restart your app after that

https://dev.to/angular/angular-apps-with-a-theme-switch-like-the-ngular-material-site-darkmode-3mno/comments